# git clone is slow - can I just copy an existing clone to a new directory?

Tags: git

We have a git repository which is rather large but which has rather few files actually present in the workspace.  Due to its size and our draconian anti-virus settings it takes quite a while to clone, which makes it more tedious to work with a lot of small branches (as Eclipse gets very confused when git manipulates the maven projects in the workspace).

Hence I would like to have a faster way to create a new git checkout "next" to an existing clone in the file system (but completely independent from it) at the exact same branch and commit as the existing clone, and I wondered if I could simply make a plain copy of the folder containing `.git` and continue working in the two projects independently.

(Also I remembered seing something about git cloning on a local file system and saving space with hardlinks.  This is not important but may be nice if it works on Windows.)

So, can I simply copy an existing git workspace (including .git) to get the same result as a new `git clone`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can copy or move a git directory. There is nothing preventing it.

If you use another user, or want to use different remote repositories, you might want to change what's inside the `.git/config` file after that but that's all.

This being said, I don't see why copying the repository would be faster than cloning it locally. It should be the reverse as the work directory can be recreated from the `.git` directory (if you copy just this directory, simply do `git reset --hard` after).

Comment: To my understanding the local clone makes the new clone point back to the existing clone, and I have to set up origin again.  I want them to be completely unaware of one another.

Comment: You may change the origin by simply changing the `.git/config` file. It's clear and safe. But origin is just a name, just like all other remote repositories you might define.

Comment: I use git reset a lot. If I need to do any post-op reconfiguration after cloning, it is easier _for me_ to just copy the folder.